# Confuse in a very simple SQL insert syntax

Tags: sql

There is a table including the data items shown below.   Which of the following SQL 
statements can insert a new row in the “student” table?

```
Name        Null?       Type 
STUD_ID    NOT NULL   NUMBER(3) 
NAME       NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(25) 
ADDRESS               VARCHAR2(50) 
GRADUATION            DATE 

a)  INSERT INTO student (stud_id, address, graduation) 
VALUES (101, ‘Dave’, ‘100 Happy Lane’, ‘2001-06-14’); 
b) INSERT INTO student (stud_id, address, name, graduation) 
VALUES (101, ‘100 Happy Lane’, ‘Dave’, ‘2001-06-14’); 
c)  INSERT INTO student 
VALUES (101, ‘100 Happy Lane’, ‘2001-06-14’, ‘Dave’); 
d) INSERT INTO student 
VALUES (101, ‘Dave’, ‘100 Happy Lane’, ‘2001-06-14’);
```

The question does not mention which DBMS, so I think this regards the common SQL syntax, not any particular one

As i can see, option `b` and `d` are all correct, but we only can choose one, and I can see no difference whether `b` or `d` is executed !

Of course, in the long run, `b` is the better syntax in case the table's structure is modified

Comment: You need to use regular single quotes for string literals: `'Dave'` **not** `‘Dave’`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I know, but this is just a pseudo-sql syntax, so it's ok

Comment: Given your example the answer is "***no** statement would insert a row in the table*" because none of them is valid SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have smart quotes in the question, which are not accepted by SQL (in general). I assume these are a typographical error. In other words, all of these would generate a SQL error for most databases.

Second, (b) and (d) look correct for most databases. However, the code is not database agnostic `varchar2()` is the standard string type for Oracle and `NUMBER(3)` is also Oracle-specific.  Oracle's *default* date format is *not* YYYY-MM-DD. So, all of these would fail in Oracle (using default settings). This could easily be fixed by doing one of the following:

```
INSERT INTO student (stud_id, address, name, graduation) 
    VALUES (101, '100 Happy Lane', 'Dave', DATE '2001-06-14');
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO student (stud_id, address, name, graduation) 
    VALUES (101, '100 Happy Lane', 'Dave', '14-Jun-2001');
```

or using `to_date()`.

So, I am quite confused by what the right answer would be. However, your interpretation is correct in general. (b) and (d) (or slight variations thereof) would both insert data. (b) is better because it uses a column list.

Answer (score 1):

b)

```
INSERT INTO student 
       (stud_id,          address,   name,   graduation) 
VALUES (    101, '100 Happy Lane', 'Dave', '2001-06-14');
```

You need to specify each column in the correct order
(spaces and enters do not matter. Also, use single quotes (') instead of curly quotes or back quotes (`)

d) may also work on most databases, but b is better: it is more widely supported and in real life better because your insert will still work correctly if columns are added or the column order is changed.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same thought, just choose which one is better, I think

Comment: maaaybe the question is aimed at the distinction between UPPERCASE in the table definition for the columns and lower case in the insert statement. Although the few DB engines I know would not have a problem with this

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, all four fields should be inserted in DB table, i.e. STUD_ID, NAME, ADDRESS and GRADUATION, all four should be part of insert as in 2), but should be in correct order, with string or date values within single quote

```
INSERT INTO student (stud_id, name, address, graduation) 
VALUES (101, 'Dave', '100 Happy Lane', '2001-06-14');
```

In any case STUD_ID, NAME fields are Not Nullable, so some data has to be there. However, if you miss ADDRESS or GRADUATION field, they will take Null values, e.g. in

```
INSERT INTO student (stud_id, name) VALUES (101, ‘Dave’);
```

a) and c) are invalid.
Syntax wise, b) is better, but as mentioned above has to be right order

Comment: Thanks but i'm not asking about this

Comment: @f855a864 Syntax wise, b) is better, but as mentioned above has to be right order

Comment: yes it is in the right order, may be you misread it